# Hack javascript angular controller code on client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I'm developing an application in AngularJS and I'm wondering whether it is possible for someone to "hack" the controllers from a client pc. For example, if from my controller I am calling a sql procedure, and I pass 2 parameters to the procedure, can these parameters be edited from a browser? If so, how?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. How can it be 'hacked'? There's nothing to hack because there's no security in client side code. A user can tamper any script that is executed in his/her own browser.

Comment: the question is, are you able to rewrite the functionality of the controller from a browser? For example, if from my controller I am calling a sql procedure, and I pass 2 parameters to the procedure, can these parameters be edited from a browser?

Comment: @Janey You should assume everything can be edited. Even if the source code is difficult to edit directly, someone could just open the console or another program and submit an ajax request to your endpoint with any parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of procedure you refer to, because the question contains no code. The functionality can *always* be rewritten by a user. It's his/her browser. He has full control of it. The only concern is how easily this is done.

Comment: the user has the control over the client side, he can even append new scripts (like jQuery) with `document.createElement("script");`, here is a discussion about it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200790/how-easy-is-it-to-hack-javascript-in-a-browser

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: I would also make sure that the parameters accepted by your sql procedure are cleansed to make sure you aren't susceptible to SQL Injection.

Comment: You won't be calling SQL procedures from Angular app. You request this from the app to the server via API and the server will do this for you by connecting to SQL. Then the Qn will be hacking the Auth token to call that api! If your browser is hacked then its possible.